# means of a matrix with varying values per row

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataset with returns and NA´s. My aim is to build three portfolios for every row. My problem is that I only want to use values without NA:

```
Returns<-matrix(c(3,5,4,13,6,8,12,18,25,NA,15,2,1,12,8,19,NA,NA,NA,NA,13,17,9,4,16,3,5,7,NA,NA),3,10,byrow=T)
```

Computation of values without NA´s per row:

```
max.value<-matrix(nrow=nrow(Returns),ncol=1)
for (i in 1:nrow(Returns)) {max.value[i,]<-sum(!is.na(Returns[i,]))}
```

Now, I know that I have 9 values for row 1, 6 values for row two and 8 for row three: What I want looks like this:

```
row1 (9 values without NA): mean(value 1-3)=P1; mean(value 4-6)=P2; mean(value 7-9)
row2 (6 values without NA): mean(value 1-2)=P1; mean(value 3-4)=P2; mean(value 5-6)  
row3 (8 values without NA): mean(value 1-3)=P1; mean(value 4-6)=P2; mean(value 7-8)
```

For me it is important that the number of values in the portfolios depends on the max.value.
If I solve my problem "per hand", it would look like this:

```
P1.1<-mean(Returns[1,1:3])
P1.2<-mean(Returns[2,1:2])
P1.3<-mean(Returns[3,1:3])
P1.RX<-rbind(P1.1,P1.2,P1.3)

P2.1<-mean(Returns[1,4:6])
P2.2<-mean(Returns[2,3:4]) 
P2.3<-mean(Returns[3,4:6])
P2.RX<-rbind(P2.1,P2.2,P2.3)

P3.1<-mean(Returns[1,7:9])

P3.2<-mean(Returns[2,5:6])
P3.3<-mean(Returns[3,7:8])
P3.RX<-rbind(P3.1,P3.2,P3.3)
Returns_new<-cbind(P1.RX,P2.RX,P3.RX)
```

I want automise this code (because I want to inetgrate more data) and my first idea was:

```
P1.test<-matrix(NaN,3,1)
for (i in 1:nrow(Returns){
for (k in 1:(max.value/3)) {P1.test<-mean(Returns[i,k])}}
```

But it does not works and I hope anyone has an idea and can help me.
Kind,
Jordan

Comment: Many of these functions have an argument `na.rm`, which, when set to `TRUE`, ignore `NA`s.

Comment: One can use the na.rm=TRUE option in order to perform the calculation.  For example: `mean(Returns[2 ,], na.rm=TRUE) `

Comment: Ditto what is said above. The `mean` function defaults to `na.rm = FALSE` if this argument is not specified. As a result it causes the `mean` of a vector containing `NA` to return `NA`. With `na.rm = TRUE`, `NA` values will be removed before the mean is calculated`.

Comment: if you want to know the mean per row, there is a `rowMeans` function (you'll also have to set `na.rm` to `TRUE`)